# innodb non-identifying foreign key requires key to be present?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

i am creating a database with a EER Diagram and used non-identifying foreign key relationships to create my foreign key.

**what i need for my foreign keys:**

- Default values should be `0` and should be used when no value is given for the FK
- the presences of the keys in the related table should not be required
- dont allow `null` values

**what i get when synchronizing data models:**

- Default values are not synced to DB from EER Diagram
- Default values are not used when implemented manually
- the presences of the keys in the related table are required
- FK fields dont allow nulls (yay!)

what am i doing wrong? i tought i had read on the web that non-identifying Foreign keys did what i needed? if everything fails i could create simple columns and only put an index on em but i tought it could be handy in the future to use foreign keys plus it looks better in my EER Diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A non-identifying Foreign key means that your entity can exists without relation to the other entity, and you got it.
But technically in mysql this is achived by using null and not 0, which means instead "linked to an entity with ID=0"

Comment: thnx for the info! so basically this means that i cant use any kind of foreign key provided by MYSQL or the EER Diagram when i want to default the non-existing FK to 0? too bad:(

Comment: Yes. That's beacause NULL means "no value", zero is actually a value, and a value in a FK must referer to something